# Multiple User types and Roles for Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, web

How can I make multiple user types with different roles and access for Django with different access roles and functions for each user type? I'm relatively new with Django and I just need some guidance on where should I go next.

Right now I followed some tip I found online and I went with thisusing abstract user and I plan to replace the User template but I'm not completely sure if I'm going to go all in or if I need to modify this for later. I'm also not sure If I have to create another seperate app for each of the access type or do I have to stick with this app that I created. Right now my goal is to create a database that should contain the intended roles:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES= (
        (1, 'pqa'),
        (2, 'tester'),
        (3, 'test_lead'),
        (4, 'test_manager'),
        (5, 'admin'),
        )
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    active= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    birth_date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    hire_date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    user_type=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

I'm not sure what to do next to be honest, I just need some help or a hint on what to do next. TIA!

Comment: You don't need to create another app for each of access type. You can just add rules for views. Something like: if request.user.user_type=5 do something else return 'you didn't have access for this operation'

Comment: Ahh yeah that's what I was thinking but I don't know if it's possible. But do I have to create an app for that function? also how do I define if a user has admin access from the get go? I tried something like:     is_admin=user_type='admin'

Comment: I think I got it. So I think i should still keep "is_staff" and "is_admin" variables but also keep the user_type for setting restrictions and what not? is that right? For context, only the admin has the right to modify the user_type and maintain the site, but the rest are just employees but they have access to special features but not to the point of having the ability to make changes in the actual DB.